# Decimal to Binary convert in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal, data-conversion

My simple program fails to convert 7 to 111 (the current code gives 101). I know `myArray[]` and the last `printf()` can be improved, but we can talk about that next time.

```
int main() {
    int myDecimal, quo, rem;
    int i = 0; //counter
    int myArray[3];
    printf("Enter valid decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &myDecimal);

    while(quo != 1){
        quo = myDecimal / 2;
        rem =  myDecimal % 2;

        myArray[i] = rem;
        myDecimal = quo;
        i++;
    } myArray[i] = quo;

    printf("\nBinary: %d %d %d", myArray[i + 2], myArray[i + 1], myArray[i] );  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated note, quo should be initialized to some value on the off chance the garbage value in memory Is 1. I'm currently looking at the rest of the code...

Comment: At the end of the loop, what is the value of `i`?

Comment: Do you include stdio.h? When I run the code it works just fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude after two iterations of while, i = 2

Comment: @starlight yeah it's included. Really? I get still get 101, weird.

Comment: @ReiAllenPhillipRamos Yes, and so would not then `i + 1` (and `i + 2`) be *out of bounds*?

Comment: Also, what if the user inputs a number *larger* than `7`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh I see. (re larger than 7), I'll worry about that when the simpler problem is solved

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it works fine now! I just had to reinitialize i to 0 before printing. Noob mistake. Anyway, thanks guys!

Comment: Lastly a note unrelated to your problem, but don't use leading newline when printing with `printf`. The `stdout` file stream (which is what `printf` writes to) is by default *line buffered*. That means the output will actually be written when there is a newline in the string. If you have a leading newline you print the *previous* output, while the current output from the current `printf` call will not be printed. Make it a habit to always have a *trailing* newline in your `printf` calls.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's a great tip. It's nice to get feedback and learn good programming practices from others. I'll remember that! :)

Comment: `while(quo != 1){` -> `while(myDecimal  && i < 3){`

Comment: `int myArray[3];` -> `int myArray[3] = { 0 };`

Comment: `} myArray[i] = quo;` -> `}`

Comment: Careful with "always" - while it is in general good practice, there are sure situations you do not want to have a newline at the end of every printf (e. g. printing an array in a loop). (If you ever get in such a situation, you still can force printing out the buffered output via `fflush(stdout);`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work fine for me. have you include header files properly? and which compiler do you using ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int myDecimal, quo, rem;
    int i = 0; //counter
    int myArray[3];
    printf("Enter valid decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &myDecimal);

    while(quo != 1){
        quo = myDecimal / 2;
        rem =  myDecimal % 2;

        myArray[i] = rem;
        myDecimal = quo;
        i++;
    } myArray[i] = quo;

    printf("\nBinary: %d %d %d", myArray[i + 2], myArray[i + 1], myArray[i] );
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

I also try this. you also can try this if you want :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    long myDecimal;
    long binary = 0, i = 1;
    int rem;
    printf("Enter valid decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &myDecimal);

    while(myDecimal != 0) {
        rem = myDecimal%2;
        myDecimal = myDecimal/2;
        binary= binary + (rem*i);
        i = i*10;
    }
    printf("Binary number is %ld",binary);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some errors that should be taken care of..

1. Initialize the array because for conversion of 1, it maybe garbage 0 1
2. Don't force the `myArray[i] = quo;`
3. You should take care of printing as `i` maybe of different length and may cause unstable behavior.
4. Also initialize `quo` before use as it may lead to garbage comparison.
5. Also follow the tips in comments, they are useful.

   ```
   int main() {
   int myDecimal, quo, rem;
   int i = 0; //counter
   int myArray[3] = {0};
   printf("Enter valid decimal number: \n");
   scanf("%d", &myDecimal);
   quo = myDecimal;
   while(quo > 0){
       quo = myDecimal / 2;
       rem =  myDecimal % 2;

       myArray[i] = rem;
       myDecimal = quo;
       i++;
   } 
   printf("Binary: %d %d %d", myArray[2], myArray[1], myArray[0]);  
   return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

By your logic you have used you need to make smaller changes to get this to work.

**check.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int myDecimal, quo, rem;
int i = 0; //counter
int myArray[3];
printf("Enter valid decimal number: ");
scanf("%d", &myDecimal);
//check myDecimal whether it's above 0 after each iteration
while(myDecimal > 0){
    quo = myDecimal / 2;
    rem =  myDecimal % 2;

    myArray[i] = rem;
    myDecimal = quo; 
    i++;
} myArray[i] = quo;
//print the array in the reverse order
for(i=2;i>=0;i--){
printf("%d",myArray[i]);
}  
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

**Ouput:**
[image]

Comment: [text outputs should just be copied and paste here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). no need to capture an image